# Async bindings in JAX-WS client not working on Weblogic 10.3.4

Tags: spring, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws

I am using the container version of JAX-WS (2.1.4) and Spring's `org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` to wire up the web service client. When (in scope of a HTTP request) I call another web service operation (that happens to be on the same server) using synchronous binding everything works fine. However after generating the ws client artifacts using **enableAsyncMapping** and using the *Async equivalent of the same operation nothing happens. I have enabled Weblogic's `wsse` verbose logging but found nothing in the log files... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a `NullPointerException` in one of the `SoapMessageHandler`s. Frankly I am a bit suprised that event though the exception was not caught but propagated to the *JAX-WS* internal classes it was not logged anywhere event with **WSSE** verbose logging turned on...